# Choose random button to setText in Android

Tags: android, button, random, textview

I have a quiz with a question and two buttons where one is true and one is false. How do I randomly put the text in buttons, so that the correct answer is not always associated with the same button.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(answer1.getText().toString()) == c){

                 Toast bf = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 bf.show();

             }
            else{
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TopActivityMath.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    });

    answer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(answer2.getText().toString()) == c){

                 Toast bf = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 bf.show();

             }
            else{
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TopActivityMath.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the question is not very clear, but to get something random you can use this

```
Random rand = new Random();
int n = rand.nextInt(2); // Gives n such that 0 <= n < 2
```

Meaning n will give you 0 or 1

```
if(n == 0){ 
    answer1.setText(correctString); 
    answer2.setText(inCorrectString); 
}else{ 
    answer1.setText(inCorrectString); 
    answer2.setText(correctString); 
}
```

Comment: If it says 2+1 there are two buttons [3] and [5] where the correct one is 3. Next time there is 3+3 where buttons are [9] and [6] and 6 is correct. Random the position of the correct answer in either of buttons..

Comment: ok so you can use what I put in my answer and add some test like this: `if(n == 0){
 answer1.setText(correctString);
 answer2.setText(inCorrectString);
}else{
 answer1.setText(inCorrectString);
 answer2.setText(correctString);
}`

Comment: @BlerinaBerisha what arthur said is, you can use the above code to generate either _0_ or _1_ radomly. If its _0_, put correct option in `button_1`. If its _1_, put correct option in `button_2`. you can assign the text using `button.setText("")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int n = rand.nextInt(2);

if(n == 0){ 
answer1.setText(correctString); 
answer2.setText(inCorrectString); 
}else{ 
answer1.setText(inCorrectString); 
answer2.setText(correctString); 
}

{

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    answerEvent(answer1.getText().toString());
}
    });
answer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          answerEvent(answer2.getText().toString());
}
    });
private void answerEvent(String text){
if(text.equals(correctString)))){

Toast bf = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 bf.show();
}
            else{
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TopActivityMath.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
}
```